# DateTime parsing Exception in Linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, datetime, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple entity which is

```
public partial class Medium {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

and the following query

```
from element in db.Mediums select element
```

I also have valid data in my database (the Date property in each entry is set with the DateTime.Parse() method). However, executing the query gives the exception.

**"Cannot set the property Date to a System.String value, you must set it to a non null value of System.DateTime".**

I sincerely can't understand what is going on, I thought DateTime was supported by EF. (The exception is triggered as soon as you try to enumerate the query content, so my understanding is that the **select** part of the statement expects a Medium type but somehow fails to parse the Date part of it).

Comment: Your database does not have the Date field set to a DateTime type.  Looks like you have it being stored as varchar.

Comment: You got it. I was using an existing database and didn't remember I changed the Date type.